# Ripple Emulator for Black Berry : how to work with sql lite?

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, blackberry, ripple

Where do I have to put sql lite database in order to work with it with an application that access it using a sql lite script similar the following? :

```
function GetComuni(dbName,sqlStmt)
{
    try
    {
        if (!window.openDatabase) {
            alert('Databases are not supported on this device. Sorry', 'error');
        } else {
            var db;
            var version = '1.0';
            var maxSize = 102400;

            db = window.openDatabase(dbName, version, dbName, maxSize);

            db.transaction(
                function (tx) {
                    tx.executeSql(sqlStmt, [], function (tx, result) {
                            var schemanode = document.GetElementById('COMUNI');
                            schemanode.innerHTML = "";
                            dataset = result.rows;
                            for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {
                                item = dataset.item(i);
                                var notediv = document.createElement('div');
                                notediv.innerHTML = 'Codice Provincia:' + item['PROVINCIA'] + 'Nome:' + item['NAME'];
                                schemanode.appendchild(notediv);
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    }
    catch(ex)
    {
        alert(ex);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Simone

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to put the database anywhere.  When your application calls window.openDatabase(), the system determines where to save the DB.

However I do see a problem in your code snippet.  You call db.transaction immediate after db = window.openDatabase().  Since both of these statements are asyncronous, there is no guarantee that the database has been opened by the time you start a transaction.

Here's a working example that might help you get started?
http://blackberry.github.com/WebWorks-Samples/kitchenSink/js/html5/webdb.js